# Add Product Id Array To Custom Table From Admin

Tags: module, database

I think I've kicked the hornets nest. I have a custom db table. I am displaying a list of products in admin similar to the related products tab or the upsell tab.

I want the id's of **selected** products (those the user has ticked) to go into my database field in the form of a single-dimensional array (1,2,3,4).

Is this insane, possible, sort-of-crazy?

I have the module and the product table but I can't get the data into the database. Any pointers would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: Yes, your architecture is a bit wrong. The correct approach will be to have a relations table instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are already displaying the grid and the on a tab of the edit product page.
I'm also assuming you are only looking for a way to save the posted data into your table.
If either assumption is wrong, please rephrase your question.

First, create an observer method that is triggered when a product is saved in the admin. There are many possible events that could be used, but probably `catalog_product_save_after` in the `adminhtml` area is a good one.

In your observer method, fetch the posted ID's from the request object:

```
$ids = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('your_ids', array());
```

Then, instantiate the model (if your table data is represented by a model) or simply a resource model (if you want to only write to the table without the ORM), and pass the `$ids` to the corresponding method.

```
Mage::getResourceModel('your_module/your_class')->saveRelatedProductIds($ids);
```

Since you already managed to create the grid on the tab, I'll add in a final assumption that you know about models, resource models and event observers. If not, please ask a new question about them.